# How to represent all possible directed graphs from an edge list that contains undirected edges?

Tags: python, list, graph-theory

Consider the following edge list: ['a-->b','a-->c','b---d','c---d']

Consider as directed edges: [[a, b],[a, c]]

Consider as undirected edges: [[b, d],[c, d]]

The end objective is two lists, one for sources and another for targets of the form:

- sources: [source1, source2, ...]
- targets: [target1, target2, ...]

However, since there are undirected edges, we would have to consider all possible networks defined by choosing a direction, therefore we would need lists of lists.  These larger lists containing 2^(# of undirected edges) lists.

The desired complete lists in this case would be:

- sources_lists: [[a, a, b, c],[a, a, b, d],[a, a, d, c],[a, a, d, d]]
- targets_lists: [[b, c, d, d],[b, c, d, c],[b, c, b, d],[b, c, b, c]]

I've tried to iteratively append a new target/source to those inside lists and then append that list to the outside one, however it never seems to work out (probably due to my ineptitude...).  Yet I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make every edge directed.  Replace undirected edges with two directed edges going back and forwards.  Carry on.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't have two edges between the same pair of nodes.  That's why a single undirected edge defines two possible graphs, each containing that edge with one of the possible directions.

Comment: Why not?  This is the usual way of handling undirected edges.

Comment: What I meant was that I can't have a single graph with multiple edges between the same pair of nodes.

Comment: I understand what you meant.  What I do not understand is why you cannot have two directed links going in opposite directions between a node pair that represents an undirected link.  That is a normal way of modelling undirected links and it works very well.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought I might have been unclear.  The reason is that later I'm going to need an acyclic graph. When splitting undirected edges, one of the directions may create loops.  So my plan was evaluate all possible graphs and remove the ones who had loops.

Comment: It is meaningless to ask if a graph with an undirected edge has a cycle.  Graphs fall into three categories with regard to cycles a) all links directed, acyclic b) all links directed, cyclic and c) some links undirected, neither cyclic nor acyclic.

Comment: That is correct, however don't consider the original edge list as representing a graph (in that case, of the C category).  It is the result of a graph structure learning algorithm.  I believe it places undirected edges when neither of the directions overpowers the other, in terms of fitting the training data.  So in this case, it does make sense to make all edges directed and then evaluate all possible graphs for loops.